# route.rb refreshing route rails 2.3 to rails 4.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migrate

This is the route in rails 2.3.14 , where i have a error to migrate a rails 4.0.3.

```
 #auth controller
map.app 'auth/app/:app_token', :controller => 'auth', :action => 'app'#, :via => :post
```

I didnt find complete documentation about route in rails 4 , if someone put a link I would appreciate.

i try with this, but something is wrong.

```
match 'auth/app/:app_token' :to =>'auth#app', via[:post]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as you expect:

```
post 'auth/app/:app_token' => 'auth#app', :as => 'app'
```